# divisible searches in the array

Tags: arrays, stream

As in the title, how can I split the search in the table into many threads (for example for 4), so that each thread looks for min and max in a different part of the array.

Comment: *"I need a tip"*. Searching an array for a simple primitive value is so fast that you're going to lose performance trying to do this multi-threaded. The thread overhead is simply too large. So here is my tip: Don't do this.

Comment: I see you're already using streams (`Arrays.stream(arr)...`), so why not get multi-threading for free by using parallel streams? `Arrays.stream(arr).parallel()...`

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of `Arrays.stream(arr).toArray()`? It copies the content of `arr` into a new array, i.e. the result is an `int[]` to `int[]` copy. Since `min()` doesn't modify the array, there is no reason to make a copy, and streaming like that is just about the worst way to make a copy, if you actually needed to do so.

Comment: Apologies: I didnt quite understand are you saying that you have an array of say 100 elemens and you want to spawn 4 thread that searches min or max from [1-25][26-50][51-75][76-100] then then all arrive at a point to find min and max from all threads? and eventually global min and maximum is returned?

Comment: Also, if you are not dealing with Wrapper classes consider usnig IntStream class

Comment: @silentsudo yes, as far as the content of the assignment is concerned, this is exactly what i wanted to convey

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the answer. 1. -l have to mention that, it is probably very instance where I am going to do this task without using queue / lists (min, max). 2. -if I were to use IntStream minArray = Arrays.stream (arr) .parallel (); instead of int minArray = min (Arrays.stream (arr) .toArray ()); then I would probably have to change the constructor search method (min, max)
if I use Arrays.stream (arr) - it gets the expected result, I can probably do better, and if I use Arrays.stream (arr) .parallel () it gets "java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head@ebf105d"

Comment: @Andreas 3.- referring to "Searching an array for a simple primitive value is so fast that you're going to lose performance trying to do this multi-threaded. The thread overhead is simply too large. So here is my tip: Don't do this "- how can I write it anyway using a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using nothing but plain `Thread`.

The code has been tested with Java 7 and Java 15.

```java
// Create array to be searched, filled with random numbers 0-999
final int[] arrayToSearch = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.length; i++)
    arrayToSearch[i] = rnd.nextInt(1000);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayToSearch));

// Prepare threads and intermediate result collectors
final int PARTITIONS = 4;
Thread[] threads = new Thread[PARTITIONS];
final int[] partitionMin = new int[PARTITIONS];
final int[] partitionMax = new int[PARTITIONS];
for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
    final int partition = i;
    threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Find min/max values in sub-array
            int from = arrayToSearch.length * partition / PARTITIONS;
            int to = arrayToSearch.length * (partition + 1) / PARTITIONS;
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int j = from; j < to; j++) {
                min = Math.min(min, arrayToSearch[j]);
                max = Math.max(max, arrayToSearch[j]);
            }
            partitionMin[partition] = min;
            partitionMax[partition] = max;
            System.out.println("partition " + partition +
                               ": from=" + from + ", to=" + to +
                               ", min=" + min + ", max=" + max);
        }
    });
}

// Start threads and wait for them to complete
for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
    threads[i].start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
    try {
        threads[i].join();
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") InterruptedException ignored) {
        // Ignore
    }
}
System.out.println("partitionMin=" + Arrays.toString(partitionMin) +
                 ", partitionMax=" + Arrays.toString(partitionMax));

// Process partition intermediate results
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS; i++) {
    min = Math.min(min, partitionMin[i]);
    max = Math.max(max, partitionMax[i]);
}
System.out.println("Result: min=" + min + ", max=" + max);
```

*Sample Output*

```
[599, 65, 712, 912, 940, 372, 922, 957, 534, 362, 76, 453, 362, 993, 449, 515, 690, 730, 96, 355]
partition 0: from=0, to=5, min=65, max=940
partition 2: from=10, to=15, min=76, max=993
partition 3: from=15, to=20, min=96, max=730
partition 1: from=5, to=10, min=362, max=957
partitionMin=[65, 362, 76, 96], partitionMax=[940, 957, 993, 730]
Result: min=65, max=993
```

Answer (score 0):

As informed by @andreas you should first aim for using `stream().parallel()` which is inbuilt. For that initialize an empty array with random value for test purpose.
Then use `IntStream` here is how i have tried it.

```
    public int min() {
        return IntStream.of(intData)
                .parallel()
                .min()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Empty Stream while calculating min value"));
    }
```

Similarly to find maximum element use `max()`

To do using multiple threads create fixed thread pool based on partition, then partition the actual data and later pass partition to each thread. Here is how i have done it.

```
public void findMinMaxUsingFutures() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalPartitions);
        final List<Future<MinMax>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        final Collection<List<Integer>> partitions = partitionedData();
        for (List<Integer> items : partitions) {
            futures.add(executorService.submit(new MinMaxCalculator(items)));
        }

        final List<MinMax> minMaxes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Future<MinMax> minMaxFuture : futures) {
            final MinMax minMax = minMaxFuture.get();
            minMaxes.add(minMax);
        }
        futures.clear();
        final List<Integer> allMins = minMaxes.stream().map(minMax -> minMax.min).collect(Collectors.toList());
        final List<Integer> allMax = minMaxes.stream().map(minMax -> minMax.max).collect(Collectors.toList());
        allMax.addAll(allMins);
        final List<Integer> leftOvers = new ArrayList<>();
        leftOvers.addAll(allMax);
        leftOvers.addAll(allMax);
        Future<MinMax> minMaxFuture = executorService.submit(new MinMaxCalculator(leftOvers));
        System.out.println(minMaxFuture.get());
    }
```

[source code](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2099988)